# Connection Timeout for connecting to google cloud TPU using notebook

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory, google-cloud-tpu, tpu

I am trying to train a model using BERT. For BERT parameters I hope to be able to fine tune the parameters using my own dataset.

I am using Google Cloud platform and TPU to accelerate the training process.

I am following [this](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google-research/bert/blob/master/predicting_movie_reviews_with_bert_on_tf_hub.ipynb) tutorial just replaced the following lines:

replaced :

```
tf.estimator.Estimator(
model_fn=model_fn_par,
config=run_config_par,
params={"batch_size": BATCH_SIZE})
```

With:

```
tf.contrib.tpu.TPUEstimator(
model_fn=model_fn_par,
config = run_config_par,
use_tpu=FLAGS.use_tpu, train_batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,predict_batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

Replaced:

```
run_config_par = tf.estimator.RunConfig(
model_dir=OUTPUT_DIR,
save_summary_steps=SAVE_SUMMARY_STEPS,
save_checkpoints_steps=SAVE_CHECKPOINTS_STEPS)
```

With:

```
run_config_par = tf.contrib.tpu.RunConfig(
master=master,
evaluation_master=master,
model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir,
session_config=tf.ConfigProto(
    allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True),
tpu_config=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUConfig(FLAGS.iterations,
                                    FLAGS.num_shards))
```

And defined the following parameters:

```
my_project = MY_PROJECT_NAME
my_zone = 'us-central1-b'
cluster_resolver = tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(
        tpu=[MY_TPU_NAME],
        zone=my_zone,
        project=my_project)
master = cluster_resolver.get_master()
```

While running the following line:

```
estimator_par.train(input_fn=train_input_fn_par, max_steps=num_train_steps)
```

The notebook tries to connect to the following address 120 times but it's not successful and it returns time out error:

```
Querying Tensorflow master (grpc://10.240.1.2:8470) for TPU system metadata.
```

I have created and instance if TPU and set the notebook runtime type to TPU as well. 
Does anybody know why I can not connect to TPU using notebook?

Comment: Did you select TPU from Edit > Notebook settings > Hardware accelerator?

Comment: @AlexIlchenko Oh I have been selected that, but apparently it was changed because of restarting. I selected that again and the problem solved. Thanks

Comment: Let's make that into an answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you select TPU from Edit > Notebook settings > Hardware accelerator?